# Codeigniter not writing sessions with Sentora

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, sentora

I migrated my application to a server with Sentora but I am having trouble of getting sessions to work properly, I have set the path properly but it seems this code is not recognized. Hope you can help me? It is working perfectly fine before when I hosted it in a non-Sentora environment. I also made the sessions folder 0700 with www-data as owner.

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Comment: Have you tried with `0755` permission level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
$config['sess_save_path'] =  sys_get_temp_dir();
```

in config.php

Comment: I am getting this message, "Message: Session: Configured save path '/tmp' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created."